# How exactly do you earn status points?

Tags: wsop-poker

In the Facebook game and mobile app WSOP - World Series of Poker. You can achieve higher status levels (and additional rewards) by gaining over a certain number of status points.

The only thing the game says about these is:

> Play & Purchase to earn points and reach the next status!

But what exactly constitutes "playing". Are higher odds better for getting status points? Is it number of hands based or time based or what?